# notify-send not working

Tags: 18.04, notify-osd, notify-send, libnotify

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to use `notify-send` via terminal, but nothing happens. It gets stuck for some time and that's it.
Can someone please suggest a solution?

In syslog, it is showing the message:
`org.kde.notifications:WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout`.

I tried starting the service
`org.freedesktop.notification`
but I got an error status: unrecognised service.

The command I am trying to run is:
`notify-send "usb detected"`

Comment: You are using proper syntax? Show a command that does not work as expected, and then helpers at least will be sure it is not an issue of using a wrong command. Edit your question and add an example of a command that does not behave as you expect.

Comment: Are you running this command as root?

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 no directly from shell for testing

Comment: Do any other notifications work? What about zenity?

Comment: @ajgringo619 it didn't.

Comment: Please post the error(s) resulting in running zenity; add to your question.

Comment: @ajgringo619 thanks for your prompt reply. There was as such no error, just the syslog error which i mentioned in my query. I was able to solve it but its weird to face such issue.

Comment: have you tried including the display that you want the notification to get shown on?

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 issue is solved. my ubuntu was notification service file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, i found that there no service file named org.desktop.Notifications in my ubuntu.

So, i created org.desktop.Notifications.service with Exec having path of Notification-daemon and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

On my (x)ubuntu installation I was required to run notify-send as root in order to get it working. This is not ideal and not really recommended but you can test if it works or not.